# Insert text into WPF textbox before the old text

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

how i can Insert text into WPF `textbox` before the old text

like `old text` then  i add text `new text old text`

Comment: you mean append the new text at start. How u r providing new text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use either

```
textbox.Text="my new text" + textbox.Text;
```

or

```
 txtbox1.SelectionStart = 0;
 txtbox1.SelectedText = "my new text";
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to use [Binding Converter](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters) where you will get the *changed* data and can convert it into format you want before assigning it to UI.

Answer (score 2):

@S3ddi9
For the second option here, you might need to do:

```
txtbox1.SelectionStart = 0;

txtbox1.SelectionLength = 0; //this was missing

txtbox1.SelectedText = "my inserted text at top";
```